# NSAttributedString with emojis warns of using Times-Roman on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, core-text

Any idea what the following means? We're not requesting `.AppleColorEmojiUI`! Any `NSAttributedString` with Emojis ends up showing this in the console.

```
CoreText note: Client requested name ".AppleColorEmojiUI", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

Comment: How is the `NSAttributedString` with Emojis created?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the attributes inspector, that the attributed text is set to a supported font.  [Apple System Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/) In my case when I copied in my text, the font was set to System Font Regular 17.0.  Even though I toggled from attributed text to plain text, and set the font in code to .body, the error still occurred. Setting a symbolic breakpoint you can see the font being passed was #% and the error occurs before viewDidLoad executed where I attempted to set the font. With a valid default font, toggling to plain text or attributed text runs without the error.